# Windows 7 Embedded Default Password

Tags: windows-7, passwords, windows-embedded-7

I'm looking for the `Admin_Maintenance` default password for Windows 7 Embedded.

Does anyone know it? Or know where I can look for it?

Answer (score 1):

I would seem the default password for the Administrator account is `Administrator`.

It was the second hit on google when searching for your question title, by the way. You might have been able to find it yourself that way.

[Source](http://www.techieshelp.com/how-to-log-on-to-windows-embedded-as-administrator/)